# Mouse press and release outside of window

Tags: java, button, mouse, pressed

I have two booleans: leftPressed and rightPressed.  I need them to be set true when their respective mouse buttons are pressed and false when they are not.  The location of the mouse and whether or not the program has focus should not matter.  This program will not have a GUI.  Is this even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to obtain mouse click coordinates outside my window in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419555/how-to-obtain-mouse-click-coordinates-outside-my-window-in-java)

Comment: This isn't as trivial as you might think and I think probably requires a mouse hook on the OS. This is something that probably requires native (non-Java) code.

Comment: You can get the mouse _location_ using `java.awt.MouseInfo` but it doesn't seem to provide button info.

Comment: @DNA: Your previous answer polls the mouse, but doesn't get the button state information (ah -- as you've mentioned above). Myself, I'd first see if this is absolutely necessary because often there's a better way to solve the overall problem. If not, then I'd look into using JNA or JNI to solve this if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the answer because it doesn't address the button issue.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible, very time consuming though. Use JNA to create a global mousehook. You would have to provide implementations for each platform you planned for it to run on, etc.. For example, [here's someone who did it with windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527931/closing-a-hook-that-captures-global-input-events).

I was looking for something similar at one point but found a better way to go about it in my code. However, I did run into this [**library**](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/). It may work out for you.