# Java robot verify mouseclick

Tags: java, input, locking, mouse, awtrobot

I currently have a simple application that needs to click on certain coordinates and it does so perfectly with Java robot when the computer is not being used.

However, when the user is moving around with the mouse, the algorithm sometimes fails and misses the coordinates. Is there any way to verify the mouseclick or lock physical mouse/keyboard input for couple of milliseconds until Java robot does its job?

Comment: You can hook a mouse or keyboard with JNA, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590226/working-example-of-jna-mouse-hook) an example.

Comment: Thanks Griffin for giving me the link to the example. It was exactly what I needed and I got it working now.

Comment: @Griffin: post it as an answer

Comment: @ArneBurmeister, alright. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Arne's request, I'll post my comment as an answer.

You can hook a mouse or keyboard with JNA, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590226/working-example-of-jna-mouse-hook) an example.