# How i can make a console application which implements KeyListener?

Tags: java, keylistener

I am trying to create a simple `Java` Program which implements `KeyListener` .

I want to run my program continuously until i abort it or upon a certain condition.
What i wanted to do is after i run the program , whatever keys i pressed , it will get stored in the `out.txt` file.

```
public class StoreInFile implements KeyListener{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true){
    // **What should i do here such that it will call the keypressed event**.
    }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        try{
              FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("d:\\out.txt",true);
              BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
              out.write(e.getKeyChar());
              out.close();
              }catch (Exception ex){
              System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
              }
    }

}
```

Is it possible to achieve in console Application?
Basically i want to create a **KeyLogger** or **KeyCatcher**.
How i can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a open source framework,`jLine`:
[jLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/)

But this is not 100% java.Some native implementation is also there.

Answer (score 2):

For line based input, i.e. *"users types text, user presses enter, your program receives what the user typed"*, the `Scanner` class should do just fine.

For single character input, such as *"user presses x-key, your program receives a notification."* you'll have to look into libraries such as [CHARVA](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/) or [Java Curses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/).

Comment: If i use a scanner class to read inputs , will it store the keys pressed only while my console window is active.What if open browser and type URL , will it store the URL keys also in the file?

Comment: No. Sounds like you're after a *key logger* or *key catcher*. Here's one project targeting Linux: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jxgrabkey and here's one project targeting windows: http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html

Comment: +1 Hey.thanks for understanding my question.i want it on windows.Can you guide me a little ? Is JINTELLITYPE is a API for JAVA?

Comment: @vikiiii, yes, as most other libraries named JSomething :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Windows, I will recommend [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna), and write keyhook and/or mousehook to monitor key/mouse events. It still works when your console window is inactive.

[JNA Keyboard Hook in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078646/jna-keyboard-hook-in-windows)

[Working example of JNA mouse hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590226/working-example-of-jna-mouse-hook)