# Grabb Mouse and Keybord events from Windows with Java

Tags: java, mouseevent

I am working on a little time tracker app for my PC running Windows 7.

It is working quite well but I want to add a new feature: When there is no activity on the PC for a while, the app should remember the time when last activity was AND react with pop up on new activity (after 5 minute threshold or so)

To know, that some one is working on the computer, I would like to get informed about mouse move events and / or kexboard events in any application of Windows.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you will need to inevstigate using a JNA or JNI solution

Comment: Coool, I found this one (looks promising): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590226/working-example-of-jna-mouse-hook

Comment: Yep, that looks like a good start