# Attempted global mouse listener stops running w/o error

Tags: java

Here is some code I recently made:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit.*;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
                public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {
                    if(e instanceof MouseEvent){
                        MouseEvent event = (MouseEvent)e;
                        if(event.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED){}
                            System.out.println("test");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);

    }
}
```

It compiles completely fine. However, when I run it it runs for about 5 seconds then just quits (w/o a message on the console), and when I click my mouse during the short time the program is running no message is printed to the console. I have tried increasing the maximum memory for the program but, as I expected, there was no change other than a slightly longer run time. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use Java's GUI library to monitor the mouse globally throughout the OS, you need to use a native hook of some kind.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590226/working-example-of-jna-mouse-hook) as an example

Comment: Try adding `while(true);` at the end of the body of the `main` method

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can test this works for me

```
public static void main(String args[]) {                                                  
  Test0 t=new Test0();

  t.setVisible(true);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {
                if(e instanceof MouseEvent){
                    MouseEvent event = (MouseEvent)e;
                    if(event.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED){}
                        System.out.println("test "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                    }
                }
            }, AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);

}
```

where Test0 is some component