# How to distinguish between scrolling up or scrolling down when using jna to listen for mouse events

Tags: java, hook, mouse, jna

This is the code that uses jna to listen for mouse events.[code detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590226/working-example-of-jna-mouse-hook).

I found that the scrolling code for the scroll wheel is 522, but I can't distinguish between up and down scrolling. Can I have a way to distinguish between sliding up and down the scroll wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Windows mouse hook the WPARAM will alert you to a scroll wheel event, and the LPARAM, what is called `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT info` in the code link you've posted, will give you the details about the event, including here the wheel delta.

Pertinent MSDN links that reference this:

- [LowLevelMouseProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [MSLLHOOKSTRUCT structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much.
I found the required scrolling information in the LPARAM.
The following code can get the corresponding information:

    boolean down = Pointer.nativeValue(info.hwnd.getPointer()) == 4287102976L;